# insert xml data to mysql with simpleXML

Tags: php, mysql, xml, simplexml

I have to insert data from xml to database, but i have a problem with this specific data

```
<specifications>
    <attribute_group name="attributeGroup1">
        <attribute name="attribute1">                   
            <value>value1</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="attribute2">                   
            <value>value2</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="attribute3">                   
            <value>value3</value>
        </attribute>
    </attribute_group>
<specifications>
```

I need to insert into database something like

```
INSERT INTO specs (attr_group,attr_name, attr_value) VALUES ('$attr_group','$attr_name', '$attr_value')
```

Problem is that i dont know how to create foreach for this.

Comment: you have a typo: no closing tag for `</specifications>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `SimpleXML`, access the values and just do a normal foreach along with your insertion codes (either MySQLi or PDO).

Example Code:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string); // or load file
$insert = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO specs (attr_group,attr_name, attr_value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');

foreach($xml as $group) {
    $attribute_group = (string) $group->attributes()['name'];
    foreach($group as $attr) {
        $attribute = (string) $attr->attributes()['name'];
        $value = (string) $attr->value;
        $insert->bind_param('sss', $attribute_group, $attribute, $value);
        $insert->execute();
    }
}
```